# sample multiple different sample sizes using crossing and sample_n to create single df

Tags: r, random, tidyr, unnest

I am attempting to sample a dataframe using sample_n. I know that sample_n usually takes a single size= argument at a time, however, I would like to sample sizes from 2 to the max # of rows in the df. Unfortunately, the code I have compiled below does not do the job. The needed output would be a dataframe with an id= column or a list divided by the id column from crossing().

```
df <- data.frame(Date = 1:15,
                 grp = rep(1:3,each = 5), 
                 frq = rep(c(3,2,4), each = 5))

data_sampled_by_stratum <- df %>%
  group_by(Date) %>%
  crossing(id = seq(500)) %>% # repeat dataframes
  group_by(id) %>%
  sample_n(size=c(2:15)) %>% 
  group_by(CLUSTER_ID,Date) %>% filter(n() > 2)
```

Comment: Do you need a list that contains dfs based on different n in `sample_n()`? Like one df with n == 2, one df with n == 3 and so on?

Comment: Eventually, I will split the dataframe into lists to input into an outside function, so yes. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you had a column with different sites you could do this.

```
data_sampled_by_stratum <- data_grouped_by_stratum %>%
    group_by(siteid, Date) %>%
    crossing(id = seq(500)) %>% # repeat dataframes
    sample_n(rbinom(1,sum(siteid==i),(1-s)^2))
```